# Passing data between transformations (XML)

Tags: xml, pentaho, kettle

I want to perform a job that contains 3 transformations:

In the first I read a XML file;
In the second I get the content of that file (all the fields);
Finally I save the data in a CSV file.

How can I go from the first to the second transformation without loosing the data, and then use it in the GET data from XML Step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as all the data will fit in memory, you can store a result set from a transform in the containing job with the `Copy rows to result` step. Then in subsequent transforms you get the results from the job with `Get rows from result`.

The 'result' they're referring to is just a big buffer that's stored in the job, so it will be available to any transform that is contained by that job. It's similar to the files 'result' which records all files touched by a job.

If your data set is too large to keep in memory, you'll need to stage the data somewhere. Either in a database table, or a file somewhere. You might look into using the `Serialize to file` step for that.